# Downtime calculation in excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to calculate downtime for devices. I would like to count only those time which is laying in a particular time slot. I am calling this time slot Min & Max time. All the timestamp is with dates but when the date is changed time should calculate according to that. for one device I am able to do that but same formulas are not working for next device.

**Logic: Timestamp is 22:00 and device the last timestamp was 6:00 hours before.
And Min 6:00 AM to 18:00 PM**

So the downtime would be **2 hours**. coz last time device communicated was 16:00 hours & downtime consider at 18:00 hours.

[file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10zFAS1qfg5v56B3SP0XPU0ER3JCk8K1R/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Break it down into steps.  I will use `Time(6,0,0)` and `Time(18,0,0)` as your start/end times, but you may want to make them cell references.  I will also use `Min_Date` and `Max_Date` as the 2 timestamps you are comparing

**Step 0:** Check if the day is the same - if so, just calculate as normal.  Otherwise, carry on with the next Steps:

```
=MEDIAN(TIME(6,0,0), Mod(Max_Date,1), Time(18,0,0)) - MEDIAN(TIME(6,0,0), Mod(Min_Date,1), Time(18,0,0))
```

**Step 1:** How many **Full Days** downtime?  (i.e. `2018-01-01 12:00` to `2018-01-03 12:00` has 1 **full day**, `2018-01-02`)  Multiply this by the hours per day:

```
=Max(Int(Max_Date)-Int(Min_Date)-1, 0) * (Time(18,0,0)-Time(6,0,0))
```

**Step 2:** How much of the **First** day was downtime?

```
=TIME(18,0,0)-MEDIAN(TIME(6,0,0), Mod(Min_Date,1), Time(18,0,0))
```

**Step 3:** How much of the **Last** day was downtime?

```
=MEDIAN(TIME(6,0,0), Mod(Max_Date,1), Time(18,0,0))-TIME(6,0,0)
```

**Step 4:** Add together Steps 1, 2, and 3

Just tie those together into 1 formula, and *voilá*.

Comment: @Chronicidal First of all thank for helping me out. I tried to replicate your process but I find some difficulty. Just take a look and let me know what i did wrong with it. [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kdWaJPYGKvXNW-AAAP7VHg_nnScYoK6o/view?usp=sharing[link]

Comment: @Ambuj Looking, I think you misunderstood what I meant by `Min_Date` and `Max_Date`:  `Min_Date` is the first timestamp, `Max_Date` is the second timestamp, and it works out the time between them, excluding any time from `18:00` to `06:00`.  So, if `Min_Date`=`2018-03-01 04:00` and `Max_Date`=`2018-03-01 12:17` then the time difference will be `06:17`